# PowerShell Robocopy capture error message

Tags: powershell, robocopy

When I use robocopy with invalid source directory I get the following message returned from PowerShell. My question is is the error message "2021/12/09 01:55:41 ERROR 3 (0x00000003) Accessing Source Directory c:\artifactTempDir....The system cannot find the path specified."

Is this stored in any variable? i am just trying to capture these two lines from the entire message.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `robocopy` writes its error messages to the *stderr* stream (which it should):

```
$stdout, $stderr = (robocopy ... 2>&1).Where({ $_ -is [string] }, 'Split')
```

`$stderr` now contains any stderr output (and `$stdout` contains the stdout output).